# Show loading when syncing Realm Mobile Database

Tags: ios, asynchronous, realm, loading

Is there any way to get notified when Realm starts/ends syncing (similar to REST API approach)?

I need to show loading to the user when needed. For example, when user download the app for first time, but there is a lot off data to syncing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not available in the shipping build just yet, but we're actively working on a PR for that sort of functionality right now. You can view it here: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/4535

It will hopefully be ready to go within the next few days.